# Formatear input number con separador de miles

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un `input` de tipo `number` al cual necesito que en pantalla se muestre con separador de miles

En la base de datos lo guardo como `decimal(13,3)`

```html
<input type="number" name="QUANTITY" id="QUANTITY" value="1234.123"> 
// Output en pantalla: 1234,123
// Output en pantalla deseado: 1.234,123
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) para darle el formato del país que quieras.

```js
const formato = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE');
const numeros = [ 123, 1234, 12345, 12345.678, 12345678.9 ];

numeros.forEach(numero =>
    console.log(`${numero} -> ${formato.format(numero)}`)
);
```

Me he dado cuenta de que usando `new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES');` el número `1234` se mantiene como `1234`. Sin embargo `12345` pasa a `12.345`, lo cual encuentro extraño, pero supongo que alguna razón tendrá.

Comment: Tu código funciona, ya que formatea el número, el problema que tengo es que lo necesito mostrar formateado en el input

Comment: Has probado con `document.getElementById("QUANTITY").value = numeroFormateado;` (`numeroFormateado` es lo que te devuelva la llamada a `format()` del objeto `NumberFormat` que crees.

Comment: Tendrás que quitar `type="number"` porque parece que si lo pones, el `input` no aceptará comas.