# ¿Como colocar este codigo para que me formatee los numeros con miles y decimales?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este codigo que sin problemas formatea mi input y va agregando las divisiones de miles (puntos en este caso), pero necesito que este mismo codigo ademas de añadir puntos (.) para los miles tambien me añada comas (,) para 2 decimales. Gracias de antemano.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>DEMO MILES </title>

<script>
    function format(input) {
        var num = input.value.replace(/\./g, '');
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
            num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
            input.value = num;
        }

        else {
            alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
            input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '');
        }
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="format(this)" onchange="format(this)">
        
    </form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: ¿Necesita ser con expresiones regulares? Porque al parecer [hay una forma más corta de hacerlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/421513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo mucho más sencillo y en menos líneas de código, podemos hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

- Permitimos que solamente se ingrese números, puntos y comas.
- Dividimos al valor en dos partes (entera y decimal) con `split()` usando a la `,` como separador.
- Validamos que no haya más de dos comas (o sea más de 2 elementos, ya que usamos a la `,` como separador). Si ocurre, hacemos un `pop()` al array, eliminando el último elemento.
- Con una expresión regular, damos formato **sólo** a la parte entera, que sería el primer elemento del array obtenido con el `split()`.
- Luego unimos las dos partes (entera y decimal) usando la coma como la unión de ambos elementos.

---

**Demo:**

```js
function format(input) {
  // Primero, vamos a obtener el valor del input para eliminar todos los caracteres que no sean dígitos o comas, es decir, podremos solo ingresar no más que sólo números y comas.
  const numero = input.value.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '');

  // Luego, dividimos el valor en dos partes: la parte entera (el número antes de la coma) y la parte decimal (el número después de la coma).
  const partes = numero.split(',');

  // Cuando coloco la coma, estoy creando un elemento más en el array, entonces si la longitud del array es mayor a 2, eliminamos ese último elemento, teniendo solo 2 elementos siempre (parte entera y parte decimal).
  if (partes.length > 2) partes.pop();

  // Aquí buscamos en grupos de tres dígitos que estén seguidos por un dígito, y añadimos un punto después del primer dígito del grupo de 3 encontrado, es decir, si ingreso "12345", capturo 3 digitos luego del primero (que es "234"), y devolvemos ese mismo pero con un punto delante del primer elemento del grupo de 3 (que sería "2.34") y juntándolo sería "12.345".
  // Solo estamos dando formato al primer elemento, que es el número entero (antes de la coma).
  partes[0] = partes[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');

  // Finalmente, unimos la parte entera (ya formateada) y la parte decimal, y lo asignamos como valor del input.
  input.value = partes.join(',');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="format(this)">
```

```js
function format(input) {
  const numero = input.value.replace(/[^\d,]/g, '');
  const partes = numero.split(',');

  if (partes.length > 2) partes.pop();

  partes[0] = partes[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.');
  input.value = partes.join(',');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="format(this)">
```

Comment: En este caso estan bien las restricciones de solo numeros y una coma al teclear, sin embargo no hace las divisiones de miles como deberia, por ejemplo, al teclear 6000 para que me los fornatee a 6.000 el codigo lo formatea como 600.0

Comment: @Josebas edité mi respuesta y agregué una breve explicación, con eso debería quedar.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer los siguitens cambios:

- Suscribirte al evento [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)
- Utilizar la API de [Internalización](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) para formatear el número.

Ahora la dificultad que se presenta es dar formato a medida que se ingresa el número, para esto hay que considerar:

- Si agregamos una coma al final, quiere decir que vamos a empezar a ingresar los decimales, entonces debemos evitar borrarla (**Ref 1**)
- Si agregamos ceros (`0`) después de la coma, debemos evitar borrarlos y para esto necesitamos indicar la cantidad mínima de decimales que vamos a usar (**Ref 2**)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function format(input) {
  // Obtenemos el valor del input, borramos los puntos y reemplazamos la coma por punto
  let num = input.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace(/\,/g, '.');
  
  // Si es un número
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
  
    // Si tiene punto, indicamos la cantidad minima de decimales 
    // igual a la cantidad de digitos despues del punto (Ref 2)
    let options = num.includes('.') ? {minimumFractionDigits: num.split('.')[1].length} : {};
    
    // Formateamos
    input.value = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-AR', options).format(num);
    
    // Si termina en punto, agregamos una coma al final (Ref 1)
    if (num.slice(-1) == '.') input.value += ',';
  } else {
    alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d.]*/g, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="format(this)">
```