# Cambiar separador de miles con CurrencyPipe de Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo este inconveniente de que el separador de miles es una coma ",", pero me gustaría que fuera un punto ".", ¿hay alguna manera de hacer esto con la pipe de currency de Angular?

Tengo el siguiente código en mi template:

```
{{ value | currency : " " : "symbol" : "1.0-0" }}
```

Supongamos que `value` es igual a 1000. 
El resultado se vería así:

```
1,000
```

Pero lo que quiero lograr se tiene que ver así:

```
1.000
```

Comment: Aquí tengo un [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593131/262104) de separador de miles, quizás te pueda servir.

Comment: Debes usar la configuración de idioma de angular para modificar el comportamiento del pipe. https://angular.io/guide/i18n-optional-manual-runtime-locale