# formatear numeros con decimales

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy queriendo lograr 2 cosas:

1. que al escribir en tiempo real la cifras en el input *monto cheque* se separe por puntos decimales, por ejemplo: 45.000.000 ...........
2. que en los demás input que está mostrando dinámicamente los resultados ya logre que separe por decimales, pero está mostrando con 2 ceros al final (ejemplo 45.000.00,00), después de la coma muestra siempre dos ceros y eso quiero que no muestre.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculadora de Cheques</title>
  <style>
    label {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="chequeForm">
    <label for="fechaInicio">Fecha de Inicio de Cheque:</label>
    <input type="date" id="fechaInicio" required>

    <label for="fechaFin">Fecha de Fin de Cheque:</label>
    <input type="date" id="fechaFin" required>

    <label for="chequeDias">Cheque a = días:</label>
    <input type="text" id="chequeDias" readonly>

    <label for="montoCheque">Monto del Cheque:</label>
    <input type="number" id="montoCheque" required>

    <label for="tasaInteres">Porcentaje a Aplicar:</label>
    <input type="number" id="tasaInteres" step="0.01" required>

    <label for="montoDescontado">Monto Descontado:</label>
    <input type="text" id="montoDescontado" readonly>

    <label for="montoCobrar">Monto a Cobrar:</label>
    <input type="text" id="montoCobrar" readonly>

    <label for="gastosAdicionales">Gastos Administrativos Adicionales:</label>
    <input type="number" id="gastosAdicionales">

    <label for="montoTotalCobrar">Monto Total a Cobrar:</label>
    <input type="text" id="montoTotalCobrar" readonly>
  </form>

  <script>
    function calcularDias(fechaInicio, fechaFin) {
      return Math.ceil((fechaFin - fechaInicio) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

    function actualizarCalculos() {
      var fechaInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("fechaInicio").value);
      var fechaFin = new Date(document.getElementById("fechaFin").value);
      var montoCheque = parseFloat(document.getElementById("montoCheque").value);
      var tasaInteres = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tasaInteres").value);
      var gastosAdicionales = parseFloat(document.getElementById("gastosAdicionales").value);

      var dias = calcularDias(fechaInicio, fechaFin);

      var tasaInteresPorDia = tasaInteres / 30 / 100;
      var efectivoInteresPorDia = tasaInteresPorDia * montoCheque;
      var efectivoInteresTotal = tasaInteresPorDia * montoCheque * dias;
      var efectivoTotalAcobrar = montoCheque - efectivoInteresTotal;

     
      // Formatear números con separadores de miles y decimales sin ceros después de la coma
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', {
  style: 'decimal',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});


      document.getElementById("chequeDias").value = dias;
      document.getElementById("montoDescontado").value = formatter.format(efectivoInteresTotal);
      document.getElementById("montoCobrar").value = formatter.format(efectivoTotalAcobrar);

      var montoTotalCobrar = efectivoTotalAcobrar - gastosAdicionales;
      document.getElementById("montoTotalCobrar").value = formatter.format(montoTotalCobrar);
    }

    document.getElementById("fechaInicio").addEventListener("input", actualizarCalculos);
    document.getElementById("fechaFin").addEventListener("input", actualizarCalculos);
    document.getElementById("montoCheque").addEventListener("input", actualizarCalculos);
    document.getElementById("tasaInteres").addEventListener("input", actualizarCalculos);
    document.getElementById("gastosAdicionales").addEventListener("input", actualizarCalculos);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Una aclaración: En el punto 1 no estas separando el numero por puntos decimales, esos son puntos separadores de millares. 

El punto decimal es el que queres que no se muestre en el punto dos (en tu caso es una coma decimal). Saludos.

Comment: Hola Marcelo, puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/593123/16597) te sea útil.

Comment: Gracias Marcos es  exactamente lo que estuve necesitando crack

Comment: Ahora no sé cómo marcar tu respuesta como la que me ayudo a llegar a la solución

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener ese resultado sin los dos últimos decimales, se tiene que modificar la configuración del formatter, cambiar maximumFractionDigits a 0.

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', {
  style: 'decimal',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 0
});
```